# ADO.NET не удаляет строку

Tags: c#, ado.net

Есть такой вот код:

```
static void Main()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Autor];select * from [Messages]",@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\lab\MSD.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        DataRow v = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().First(A => A["AutorName"].ToString() == "Sergey");
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(v);
        v["AutorName"] = "Sergey1";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(v);
        SqlCommandBuilder b = new SqlCommandBuilder(ad);
        ad.Update(ds);
    }
```

Здесь я получаю некий `DataRow`, который затем я удаляю из таблицы, в участке кода `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(v);`. Далее я меняю в столбике `AutorName` имя автора на `Sergey1`, и я ожидаю, что ранее полученная переменная `v` содержит `AutorName` = теперь `Sergey1`, а `AutorInfo` = той записи которая была. То есть в целом ожидаю от кода удаление записи которая соответствует переменной `v` и добавление в конец таблицы модифицированной переменной `v` просто с исправленным `AutorName`. Однако в физической таблице выходит, что запись содержащая `AutorName` = `Sergey` не удалилась вообще, зато в конце добавилась запись `[AutorName] = Sergey1 [AutorInfo] = NULL`. Почему так получилось: 1. Не удалилась запись с `Sergey` 2. Добавленная запись не содержит `AutorInfo (null)`. Прилагаю картинку после выполнения кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте добавить после удаление: ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: попробуйте `v.Delete()` вместо `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(v);`

Comment: [Практическое руководство. Удаление строк из объекта DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/feh3ed13.aspx), [Удаление DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/03c7a3zb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, Grundy, помогло

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, небольшой ликбез: если хотите обратиться к кому-то, поставьте символ `@` перед ником и ему придет оповещение. :-) например _@PolyakovSergey_